# Laravel relationship with pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have 3 tables in my database :

```
users (id);
interests (id);
users_interests (user_id, interests_id);
```

I want to be able to fetch all the user's interests in this way :

```
$interests = $user->interests
```

This is what I wrote in the User.php model, following laravel's doc:

```
public function interests() { 
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
         'App\Interest', 'App\UserInterest', 
         'user_id', 'id', 'interest_id'
    );
}
```

but it returns empty even though the user has a game. So there has to be something I'm doing wrong

Anyone to help me ?

Comment: You can get what you want with just `hasMany` relationship !

Comment: how can I get that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a `belongs to many` would do the job:

```
public function interests() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany(
         'App\Interest', 
         'users_interests', 
         'user_id', 
         'interests_id'
    );
}
```

Quite similar to the example in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

If you were to rename `users_interests` table to `interest_user` and the column 
`interests_id` to the singular form you would just need the first parameter:

```
 public function interests() { 
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Interest::class);
    }
```

From my understanding the `hasManyThrough` is used to jump forward within a relation (also described in the docs):

> The "has-many-through" relationship provides a convenient shortcut for
>   accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation.

Comment: Glad to hear that, happy coding :)

Comment: I'd also suggest you to use the Eloquent naming conventions for the database. You'll save a lot of code and you'll improve its readability. These are very few easy rules.